# Why does upgrading Fedora from 23 to 24 downgrade tomcat

Tags: upgrade, fedora

When starting the upgrade from Fedora 23 to Fedora 24, `dnf upgrade` gives me some messages:

```
 java-1.8.0-openjdk             x86_64 1:1.8.0.92-3.b14.fc24      updates 226 k
 java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel       x86_64 1:1.8.0.92-3.b14.fc24      updates 9.8 M
 java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless    x86_64 1:1.8.0.92-3.b14.fc24      updates  32 M
 java-1.8.0-openjdk-javadoc     noarch 1:1.8.0.92-3.b14.fc24      updates  15 M
 nss                            i686   3.24.0-1.2.fc24            updates 877 k
 nss                            x86_64 3.24.0-1.2.fc24            updates 863 k
 nss-sysinit                    x86_64 3.24.0-1.2.fc24            updates  58 k
 nss-tools                      x86_64 3.24.0-1.2.fc24            updates 496 k
 php-zendframework-zendxml      noarch 1.0.2-1.fc24               fedora   14 k
 tomcat                         noarch 1:8.0.32-4.fc24            fedora   93 k
 tomcat-admin-webapps           noarch 1:8.0.32-4.fc24            fedora   45 k
 tomcat-el-3.0-api              noarch 1:8.0.32-4.fc24            fedora  107 k
 tomcat-jsp-2.3-api             noarch 1:8.0.32-4.fc24            fedora   72 k
 tomcat-lib                     noarch 1:8.0.32-4.fc24            fedora  4.1 M
 tomcat-servlet-3.1-api         noarch 1:8.0.32-4.fc24            fedora  257 k
```

I'd love to know why. There doesn't appear to be a way of getting any search engine, including stackexchange to give reasonable answers to this question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "speculate on why some versions of software are/aren't available in my particular Linux distribution's package management" isn't a programming question. (Maybe try the Unix/Linux Stackexchange site).

Answer (score 1):

Contrarily to what Jakuje says in his answer, this is indeed a downgrade:

```
$ rpmdev-vercmp 8.0.32-5.fc23 8.0.32-4.fc24
8.0.32-5.fc23 > 8.0.32-4.fc24
```

The tomcat packager made a mistake and broke the upgrade path, which is something we try to avoid in the Fedora community, specifically because it is at best confusing (as evidenced by this question) and at worst it can prevent users from running upgrades at all.

> In Fedora we want to ensure that there is always an upgrade path from Fedora release to Fedora release and from Fedora release to the packages in updates. To do that **we need to make sure the packages in the newer Fedora releases have an equal or higher `Epoch:Version-Release` (EVR) than the ones in older releases**. (emphasis mine, [source](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:Naming#Package_Versioning))

In fact, we even have a [CI check to try and avoid ever breaking the upgrade path](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Taskotron/Tasks/upgradepath), but I'm not sure that's already fully operational.

Of course, now that F24 is released, it's probably too late to do anything about it.

However, a polite email to the packager might be enough to explain to them why this is wrong, and to ask them to try and avoid doing it in the future.

You can always send an email to the maintainer(s) of a package in Fedora by writing to $package-owner@fedoraproject.org, which in your case would be tomcat-owner@fedoraproject.org

Comment: Yes, you are right. It is packaging problem. Unfortunately it was not caught in the updates, nor in the the testing of release and updates. It might cause problems to other users so fixing that would be a good idea (at least for the next users).

Answer (score 0):

If I see right, you are concerned about the update from

```
tomcat-8.0.32-5.fc23
```

to

```
tomcat-8.0.32-4.fc24
```

This is **not** a downgrade. There is changed *release*, but the *version* is still the same. The release number might differ between Fedora releases (fc23 -> fc24), because they do not follow the same update cycle (you might get more updates for Fedora 23 than Fedora 24, theoretically).

Source: http://koji.fedoraproject.org/koji/packageinfo?packageID=12023